# operator= on fd_set - socket communication linux

Tags: c, select

I'm writing a program that uses select(), given a to-read fd_set.
In the program, i'm saving two fd_sets:
1. fd_set named DB with all the fd's i can deal with.
2. fd_set named toSelect - which i send to the select() method, and handles later after the select() returns.

Before calling to select(), i'm doing this:
toSelect = DB;
In order to copy all the fd's in DB to the toSelect fd_set.
Since my program isn't working so well (coming up with the message "Connection reset by peer"), there's probably something wrong with my code.
Is this assignment is ok?
If not, how can i copy one fd_set to another without using the operator= ?
Thank you.

Comment: When posting here, please try to differentiate between C and C++ - the select() API is a C/POSIX API.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `toSelect = DB`, try using the FD_ISSET and FD_SET macros to copy the values from one to the other, and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

The internal details of fd_set including whether or not operator= will be defined (and pass compilation) is implementation defined. The only things fd_set promises you is the interface it provides in the form of the macros (or functions) FD_SET, FD_CLEAR, FD_ISSET, FD_ZERO.

If you want to be able to use operator= you can write your own wrapper class for it.

Comment: Say what? Assignment is defined for all C data types, including user-defined ones, and in C++ for all POD types. fd_set has nothing specifically to do with C++.

Comment: @Neil Yes, I mistakenly thought it might not pass compilation, but being defined doesn't make such a statement right. Using operator= is not part of the promised interface for fd_set.

Comment: Yes, it is - fd_set is a POD.

Comment: `fd_set` is not explicitly specified as POD, but due to other requirements, unless it relies on nonstandard extensions in your C compiler, it must be POD.

Comment: @R.. For the sake of my education, can you please elaborate on these requirements or provide a link?

Comment: If `fd_set` utilized any allocated memory, there would be no way for a standard C implementation to free it. One could try to construct a hypothetical `fd_set` implementation using the nonstandard but common `alloca`, but then you'd run into problems because, as long as the `fd_set` does not cease to exist, it's valid to continue using it after the function that called `FD_*` returns (and in fact this would be a very common usage if you factor setting up the `fd_set` into its own function in your application).

Comment: I see what you mean. It will take quite a creative implementation to make operator= not work.